# when clicking on action button in frappe, my route is prefixed by /app

Tags: frappe

I have created an action for my doctype in Frappe framework, the action should call a route lets say `/ABC`. The problem is that when I click on the action button in doctype change view it redirects me to `/app/ABC`

I also tried to redirect using hooks `/app/ABC` to `/ABC` but it didn't work (I have to refresh page so that it works)

Answer (score 0):

I had to resolve this issue by using JS, the problem with that function it will always return a URL with the "/app" attached to it

```
const currentUrl = window.location.href;
const parts = currentUrl.split('/');
const result = parts.slice(0, 3).join('/');
const new_url = result+"/video_comference";
window.location.href = new_url;
```

The Code above will take you to your desired page.
Hope this helps you out